# Best way to update elements from an has_many relationship without instantiating full models and triggering the callbacks

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

This is something I'm trying to do now: A has_many Bs. B has certain callbacks that need to be triggered. Just, when I save from A, I want something to be updated in Bs. Since the Bs can be 10000, I would like not to load them into memory, and still have the benefit of seeing the callbacks triggered. What is the best strategy for this?

And please, no "find_each" or any find by batches variant, I'm aware of them and they will be my last resort in case nothing else works.

Comment: Having more context would likely be helpful. What exactly are you trying to do in the callback in `B`?

Comment: Let's say that, when an A updates its name, all its Bs need to update it's timestamp. But since each B belongs to C, I want the timestamp in C to be updated. I'm trying to avoid loading the 10000 Bs and for each its corresponding C. I would like to update all Bs at once and trigger callbacks to its Cs.

Comment: You can't trigger true callbacks *(a callback being something defined through a `before_...` or `after_...` method invocation)* for a model instance without loading the database record into an ActiveRecord instance where those callbacks are defined. If you're just trying to update timestamps for related `B` and `C`, you can do this with a couple raw SQL queries in a `after_save` callback in `A`.

Comment: You should also look into something like [Delayed Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) for this sort of long running task. I'm not suggesting there isn't a more efficient way to accomplish your specific task, but when dealing with large data sets as you are, it's a perfect use case for a job queue.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this problem, I use this solution

- define "callback methods" in a class and use they with ids,
- define really callbacks in a instance and pass id of record in "class callback"

example of code:

```
class Post < AR
  has_many :comments
  after_save do |post|
    Post.recalculate_counters(post.comment_ids)
  end
end

class Comment < AR
  belongs_to :post

  after_save :recalculate_couters

  def self.recalculate_couters(ids)
    ...  huge and slow update statement ...
  end

  def recalcuate_couters
    self.class.recalculate_couters([id])
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you mean `Comment.recalculate_counters(...)` in your `Post` class.

Comment: I fail to see how your huge and slow update statement is going to not fully load the models and trigger the callbacks. This was exactly the point of the question. Can you please go further into that subject?

Comment: @ChuckE The "huge and slow update statement" uses plain sql in few Model.update_all call.

Comment: These won't trigger the callbacks on the Bs. That's my whole problem with them, otherwise, they would be THE solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way you can have the callbacks executed without loading the models. However, if you give up using callback you can use `update_all` that performs really fast.

You just use:

```
B.update_all({:timestamp => Time.now}, { :a_id => id })
```

Comment: Yes, the main concern is still the callbacks. Otherwise you can rewrite that with: a.bs.update_all(:timestamp => Time.now). The ActiveRecord::Relation has access to the same query helpers.